# Which version of jetty is compatible with cometd-3.0.2

Tags: java, jetty, cometd

Currently I am using *cometd 3.0.2* (the latest one). Trying to do a simple handshake it gives me the following error:

With *jetty 7.4.4*:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/client/api/ContentProvider
```

With *jetty 9.2.3*:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/util/ajax/JSON
```

This is the code that I am trying to run:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import org.cometd.client.BayeuxClient;
import org.cometd.client.transport.ClientTransport;
import org.cometd.client.transport.LongPollingTransport;
import org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpClient;

public class MyClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        // Create (and eventually set up) Jetty's HttpClient:
        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
        // Here set up Jetty's HttpClient, for example:
        // httpClient.setMaxConnectionsPerAddress(2);
        httpClient.start();

        // Prepare the transport
        Map<String, Object> options = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        ClientTransport transport = new LongPollingTransport(options, httpClient);

        BayeuxClient client = new BayeuxClient("http://localhost:8080/cometd", transport);
        client.handshake();
        boolean handshaken = client.waitFor(1000, BayeuxClient.State.CONNECTED);
        if (handshaken) {
            System.out.println("Yey");
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone know which *jetty* is compatible with the latest *cometd*? Or any other *cometd*?

Comment: If you are using maven, can you post your pom.xml ?

Comment: I'm not using maven. Do I have to? Sorry I'm new to this.

Comment: Maven isn't required, but since there are so many dependencies, you might want to look into maven, or ant+ivy, or gradle (really any other build tool that does proper transitive dependency resolution).  As the problem you are describing just screams bad/missing/misplaced artifacts.

Answer (score 1):

CometD 3 works with any Servlet 3.0 or greater Servlet Container.
Jetty 9.2.x is the recommended Servlet Container to use.

Having said that, Joakim is right in saying that CometD depends on other libraries, and as such you should use a build tool that does this job for you.
Maven is such recommended tool.

Have a look at the updated [installation instructions](http://docs.cometd.org/3/reference/#_installation), at the [primer](http://docs.cometd.org/3/reference/#_primer), and at the [tutorials](http://docs.cometd.org/tutorials) to get started.

I recommend that you follow the primer instructions. Even if you don't like Maven, you can install it temporarily, follow the primer, and once you have the skeleton CometD application that the primer produces you, you may uninstall Maven if you so desire (but then you are on your own to build your application).